# Run SpringBatch Step parralel and sequential

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

In a Spring-Batch job, I have two business actions, A and B, each has several steps (1, 2, 3).
I want to run A1 and B1 in parallel, when both have ended, I want to run A2 and B2 in parrallel:

```
start
    A1-B1 in parallel
wait for both ended
    A2-B2 in parrallel
wait for both ended
    A3-B3 in parrallel
...
```

I tried something:

```
@Bean
public Job test() {
    SimpleFlow splitFlow = new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("Sequential Flow")
                    .split(new SyncTaskExecutor())
                    .add(flow1(), flow2())      
                    .build();

    return jobs.get("test").start(splitFlow).end().build();
}

private Flow flow1() {
    return new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("parralel 1").split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
                    .add(new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("A1").start(stepA1()).build(), 
                        new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("B1").start(stepB1()).build())
                    .build();
}

private Flow flow2() {
    return new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("parralel 2").split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
                    .add(new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("A2").start(stepA2()).build(), 
                        new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("B2").start(stepB2()).build())
                    .build();
}
```

It is working.

but it's also ugly and almost unreadable. Is there an easier to do it ?

(I'am ok to change from step to job, to run to jobs and have them waiting for each other, but how to do it ?)

**Edit**: 
I found the equivalent in xml config :

```
<batch:job id="test">
    <batch:split id="step_1" next="step_2">
        <batch:flow> 
             <batch:step id="A1"/>
        </batch:flow>
        <batch:flow> 
             <batch:step id="B1" />
        </batch:flow>
    </batch:split>
    <batch:split id="step_2">
        <batch:flow> 
             <batch:step id="A2"/>
        </batch:flow>
        <batch:flow> 
             <batch:step id="B2" />
        </batch:flow>
    </batch:split>
</batch:job>
```

All my config is currently in Java config, but maybe for these jobs the xml config is easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the readability, there are two options:

a) Format your code differently

```
private Flow flow1() {
    return new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("parralel 1")
            .split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
            .add(
                    new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("A1").start(stepA1()).build(),
                    new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("B1").start(stepB1()).build()
            ).build();
}

private Flow flow2() {
    return new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("parralel 2")
            .split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
            .add(
                    new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("A2").start(stepA2()).build(),
                    new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("B2").start(stepB2()).build())
            .build();
}
```

b) extract methods and variables

```
private TaskExecutor executor() {
    return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
}

private Flow flow1() {
    Flow subFlow1 = new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("A1").start(stepA1()).build();
    Flow subFlow2 = new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("B1").start(stepB1()).build();
    return new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("parralel 1")
            .split(executor())
            .add(subFlow1, subFlow2)
            .build();
}


private Flow flow2() {
    Flow subFlow1 = new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("A2").start(stepA2()).build();
    Flow subFlow2 = new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("B2").start(stepB2()).build();
    return new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("parralel 2")
            .split(executor())
            .add(subFlow1, subFlow2)
            .build();
}
```

BTW, I'm pretty sure you should be using the same `TaskExecutor` from both flows. You can achieve that by making the executor() method public and marking it as `@Bean`. Spring will then make sure the underlying object is only created once (see [The IOC Container](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html)). So the executor() method above should actually read:

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor executor() {
    return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
}
```